# return array from database with function

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code for reading values from database and returning array:

```
public function avtorizacije($user)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM uporabniki_avtorizacije WHERE userId=?";
    if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
        throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

    $this->stmt->bind_param("i", $user);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    $this->stmt->store_result();

    if( $this->stmt->num_rows == 0)
        return "";

    $this->stmt->bind_result($value);
    $this->stmt->fetch();

    return $value;
}
```

And here is the error I get:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in ...

I need to return all values from selected row in database.

Comment: `stmt->bind_result` __must bind all fields__ selected from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `bind_result` to an `array` to return an `array`;

Just change `$col` index names to the field names it has in your database table in the order you retrieve them from your SQL string.

```
$col['username'] = '';
$col['col2'] = ''; // change index here and below with reference to the table fields you're fetching
$col['col3'] = '';
$col['col4'] = '';

$this->stmt->bind_result($col['username'], $col['col1'], $col['col1'], $col['col1'] );

$this->stmt->fetch();
return $col;
```

Or just use the code below. It uses `get_result()` and `fetch_assoc()` to instantly return records in array format.

**Alternative:**

```
public function avtorizacije($user)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM uporabniki_avtorizacije WHERE userId=?";
    if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
        throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

    $this->stmt->bind_param("i", $user);
    $this->stmt->execute();

    $result = $this->stmt->get_result();

    if( $result->num_rows == 0)
        return "";

    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Comment: do I really must manually name all fields to bind them?  Is there no other way

Answer (score 0):

Here you use

```
`SELECT *`
```

pull all fields from table,

Here you bind one variable.

```
$this->stmt->bind_result($value);
```

Here is your error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in ...

Now I would bet you have more then one field in your table, no?  So you need to bind a variable for each field in the order they are in the query.

This said I don't us Mysqli, for like 4 years, so forgive me if I am mistaken... lol  (I use PDO now, so much nicer)

You can clearly see this in the first example on the Documentation page.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php